# iOS Robby Hanson XMPP framework resources

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using Robbie Hanson's XMPP framework. I understand for a single jabber id, you can have multiple resources. How do you add multiple resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resource is a string identifying a particular connection to the server. To create a new one you simply make a new connection to the server.